# how can i align the "fa-message" and the avatar and text along each other

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i tried to align fa-message icon , the avatar and text along each other but the text is moving under the avatar

this is my code:

```
<div> 
    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"><sup>
    <span class="badge badge-success">5</span></sup></a></span>
    <span> <img src="./girl.jpg" class="img-circle img2">
    <i class="picsname2">Welcome,<br>John Doe</i></span>
</div>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjHEM.png)

Comment: possible that your div has a fixed width that is causing to move the text under the avatar

Comment: No, the div don't have a fixed width

Comment: make the `i` display as `inline-block` and that solves it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
i.picsname2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
    <sup><span class="badge badge-success">5</span></sup>
  </a>
  <span> 
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/30/30" class="img-circle img2">
      <i class="picsname2">Welcome,<br>John Doe</i>
    </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your width or use css property `display: inline-block` or remove that `<br/>` used before the name.

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox it's an easy task. Adjust then the space between elements.

```css
.flex-row-centered {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="flex-row-centered"> 
    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"><sup>
    <span class="badge badge-success">5</span></sup></a></span>
    <span class="flex-row-centered"> <img src="./girl.jpg" class="img-circle img2">
    <i class="picsname2">Welcome,<br>John Doe</i></span>
</div>
```

Or (since you tagged the question with bootstrap-4) using bootstrap 4 classes:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex flex-direction-row align-items-center"> 
    <a href="#" class="mr-2"><span class="fa fa-envelope"><sup>
    <span class="badge badge-success">5</span></sup></a></span>
    <span class="d-flex flex-direction-row align-items-center"> <img src="./girl.jpg" class="img-circle img2 mr-2">
    <i class="picsname2">Welcome,<br>John Doe</i></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix #1: font-awesome icons need empty elements

Fix #2: Your tags need to be nested properly. The `A` and `SPAN` elements are overlapping. So try this.

```
<a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
    <sup><span class="badge badge-success">5</span></sup>
</a>
```

Now you can set the style `display:inline-block;` to the `span` element so it becomes a box preventing text wrapping under the icon.

```
<span style="display:inline-block;">
    <img src="./girl.jpg" class="img-circle img2" />
    <i class="picsname2">Welcome,<br>John Doe</i>
</span>
```

Next the reason the `.picsname2` text is on a new line is because you've used a `<br>` element to break line.

Either try:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center;"> 
    <a href="#">
        <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
        <sup><span class="badge badge-success">5</span></sup>
    </a>
    <span style="display:inline-block;">
        <img src="./girl.jpg" class="img-circle img2" />
        <i class="picsname2">Welcome,<br />John Doe</i>
    </span>
</div>
```

or remove the line-break like this:

```
<div> 
    <a href="#">
        <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
        <sup><span class="badge badge-success">5</span></sup>
    </a>
    <span>
        <img src="./girl.jpg" class="img-circle img2" />
        <i class="picsname2">Welcome, John Doe</i>
    </span>
</div>
```

The image will need to be a fixed size to prevent the height changing. Even if we use Flex box you don't want the height of the navbar changing too much otherwise your wasting content space on mobile devices.